# How to change the default inheritance feature so that I don't have to manually disable it every time?

Tags: windows-10, security, permissions, file-permissions

The default setting is that a folder/files always inherits the permissions from its immediate parent folder. This can be disabled by clicking on the button as shown below:

[image]

However I want to change the default setting to be 'inheritance disabled' - so that whenever a new folder/file is created, it should not inherit from its parent.

1. Is is possible to override the default windows setting globally? - so that every folder/file henceforth created will have inheritance disabled.
2. Is is possible to override the default windows setting on a folder? - so that all the folders/files inside that folder do not inherit permissions.